# Showing what quarter of a financial year a date is in

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, finance

I'm trying to construct a query that will map two columns, one, a date from a table, the second column an alias to show what quarter and financial year the date falls into.

Unfortunately I don't have enough knowledge of SQL to know where to begin. I know that I'd do this with a combination of `getdate()` and `dateadd(MONTH,,)` however nothing that I've put together has come close to working.

To further complicate this the financial years in Australia go from 1st July- 30th of June so quarter one of financial year 2012 would start from July 1st 2012.

I can do this without a statement however I'd much rather have it in a statement as it's going to be used in an SSRS report and a C# application and it would make maintenance significantly easier.

Comment: When do you want to apply the Australian logic? Globally or only for certain rows? Is that the only country you are dealing with which has a special financial year? Do your rows have country information in them? If not, can they be joined to a table which can provide this?

Comment: @AdamRalph Sorry, I should have specified that. This is the only country that I'll be dealing with for this report. Once I have a working statement I'll join to another table which has country information in order to ensure that this statement isn't accidentally used for another country in future.

Comment: @MichałPowaga The only reason I didn't provide any is that for the sake of this example I specified that I'd only be using one column, a date field. So example data would be any table with one column that only stores date values. The financial year / quarter would be calculated via this as an alias.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should work:-

```
SELECT
    MyDate,
    CASE
        WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 1  AND 3  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(MyDate) - 1) + 'Q3'
        WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 4  AND 6  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(MyDate) - 1) + 'Q4'
        WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 7  AND 9  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(MyDate) - 0) + 'Q1'
        WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(MyDate) - 0) + 'Q2'
    END AS Quarter
FROM
    MyTable
```

Output:-

```
MyDate        Quarter
----------    --------
2011-01-01    "2010Q3"
2011-04-01    "2010Q4"
2011-07-01    "2011Q1"
2011-10-01    "2011Q2"
```

Answer (score 14):

This method doesn't require a CASE statement, and works for any monthly fiscal calendar.

```sql
    DECLARE @firstMonthOfFiscalQ1 int = 7; --1=January
    SELECT DateColumn
        , FLOOR(((12 + MONTH(DateColumn) - @firstMonthOfFiscalQ1) % 12) / 3 ) + 1 AS FiscalQuarter
        FROM SomeTable 
        WHERE 1=1;
```

Here's a quick tweak to the above as an example of how to use it to build a full financial year + quarter string ( `{year}Q{quarter}` ).

```sql
    DECLARE @firstMonthOfFiscalQ1 int = 7; --1=January
    SELECT DateColumn
        , CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(DateColumn) - IIF(MONTH(DateColumn) < @firstMonthOfFiscalQ1, 1, 0)) + 'Q' + CONVERT(varchar, FLOOR(((12 + MONTH(DateColumn) - @firstMonthOfFiscalQ1) % 12) / 3 ) + 1) AS FiscalYearAndQuarter
        FROM SomeTable 
        WHERE 1=1;
```

Comment: This is so simple and efficient, and you can set your starting quarter however you like. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 7):

I think it would be easiest to do this with `CASE`

```
SELECT
   date
   , CASE
         WHEN MONTH(date) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN 'First Quarter'
         WHEN MONTH(date) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN 'Second Quarter'
         WHEN MONTH(date) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 'Third Quarter'
         WHEN MONTH(date) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN 'Fourth Quarter'
     END AS quarter
FROM Stuff
```

Comment: Made me feel ridiculously stupid - thank-you very much, very clean.

Comment: @Michael - Don't worry about it, the solution I had in mind wasn't pretty either. <g>

Answer (score 4):

Just in case you want to do some wacky mathematical operations to avoid a case statement:

```
select mydate,
   convert(char(4), year(mydate) - (((DATEPART(qq, mydate) - ((DATEPART(qq, mydate) + 1) % 4) + 1) / -4) + 1)) + 
   'Q' + convert(char(1), ((DATEPART(qq, mydate) + 1) % 4) + 1) quar
from sampleData
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider creating an equivalent of a Date Dimension table from a data warehouse. This would have one row per day for every year your data could possibly cover (start from some reasonable epoch and go forward until some reasonably far future date).

Within this table, you would have columns describing info about every day - including calendar year, half-year, quarter, month; and fiscal year, half-year, quarter.

Your report then simply joins to this table based on date to pull this info. This gives you future support for other info about dates also, and removes the responsibility of this calculation from each individual reporting query.

Answer (score 2):

A few years late to the game, but here's my quick-easy-clean method for Australians using GetDate(). Even your accounting calendar is upside-down :)

```
SELECT CHOOSE(MONTH(GetDate()),'3Q','3Q','3Q','4Q','4Q','4Q','1Q','1Q','1Q','2Q','2Q','2Q') AS AccountingQuarter
```

The SQL choose command takes the month of the date as the parameter, then chooses from the 12 available options. Of course, most other systems would start with 1Q/Q1 in the first choice.

Comment: A long time since I needed this, but nice one!

Answer (score 1):

I found that using '*[Explosion Pills](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8738926/2337102)*' result worked, but I wanted mine to look like the answer by '*[Adam Ralph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8739030/2337102)*', however I kept experiencing errors.  I was able to work around this and created a new `CASE` example:

```
    CASE    -- Results:  2011 (Financial Year )
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 1  AND 3  THEN (YEAR(MyDate) - 1)
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 4  AND 6  THEN (year(MyDate) - 1)
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 7  AND 9  THEN (YEAR(MyDate) - 0)
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN (YEAR(MyDate) - 0)
    END AS FYr,

    CASE    -- Results:  Q4 (Financial Qtr)
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN 'Q1'
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN 'Q2'
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 'Q3'
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN 'Q4'
    END AS FQtr,

            -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22170892/2337102
    CASE    -- Results:  2011-Q4  (Financial Yr-Qtr)
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 1  AND 3  THEN concat((YEAR(MyDate) - 1), '-', 'Q3')
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 4  AND 6  THEN concat((YEAR(MyDate) - 1), '-', 'Q4')
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 7  AND 9  THEN concat((YEAR(MyDate) - 0), '-', 'Q1')
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN concat((YEAR(MyDate) - 0), '-', 'Q2')
    END AS FYrQtr,


    CASE    --  Results:  11-Q4   (Financial (short) Yr-Qtr)
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 1  AND 3  THEN concat((date_format(MyDate, '%y') - 1), '-', 'Q3')
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 4  AND 6  THEN concat((date_format(MyDate, '%y') - 1), '-', 'Q4')
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 7  AND 9  THEN concat((date_format(MyDate, '%y') - 0), '-', 'Q1')
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 10  AND 12  THEN concat((date_format(MyDate, '%y') - 0), '-', 'Q2')
    END AS FYrQtr,

    CASE    --  Results:  2011-2012/Q4  (Financial Range Yr/Qtr)
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 1  AND 3  THEN concat(YEAR(MyDate) - 1,'-', YEAR(MyDate), '/', 'Q3')
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 4  AND 6  THEN concat(YEAR(MyDate) - 1,'-', YEAR(MyDate),  '/', 'Q4')
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 7  AND 9  THEN concat(YEAR(MyDate) - 0,'-', YEAR(MyDate) + 1,  '/', 'Q1')
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 10  AND 12  THEN concat(YEAR(MyDate) - 0,'-', YEAR(MyDate) + 1,  '/', 'Q2')
    END AS FRangeQtr,

    CASE    --  Results:  11-12/Q4  (Financial Range (short) Yr/Qtr)
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 1  AND 3  THEN concat((date_format(MyDate, '%y') - 1),'-', (date_format(MyDate, '%y')), '/', 'Q3')
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 4  AND 6  THEN concat((date_format(MyDate, '%y') - 1),'-', (date_format(MyDate, '%y')), '/', 'Q4')
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 7  AND 9  THEN concat((date_format(MyDate, '%y') - 0),'-', (date_format(MyDate, '%y') + 1), '/', 'Q1')
            WHEN MONTH(MyDate) BETWEEN 10  AND 12  THEN concat((date_format(MyDate, '%y') - 0),'-', (date_format(MyDate, '%y') + 1), '/', 'Q2')
    END AS FRangeQtr2,
```

I am adding my answer hoping it will help someone else who comes via Google and experiences issues.

Answer (score 1):

We already have a sysDate table that contains dates from Jan 1, 1900 to Dec 31, 2030 that we use for processing.  We were asked to do fiscal year handling, and so we modified our table to include `FiscalYearString varchar(9)`, `FiscalYear int` and `FiscalQuarter int` columns.

The script we use to update these columns is this:

```
DECLARE @StartingMonthOfFiscalYear INT = 4 -- 1-Jan, 2-Feb, 3-Mar, 4-Apr, 5-May, 6-Jun, 7-Jul, 8-Aug, 9-Sep, 10-Oct, 11-Nov, 12-Dec

UPDATE sysDate
SET FiscalYear = CASE WHEN MONTH([Date]) < @StartingMonthOfFiscalYear 
                        THEN YEAR([Date])-1 
                        ELSE YEAR([Date]) END,
    FiscalYearString = CASE WHEN MONTH([Date]) < @StartingMonthOfFiscalYear 
                        THEN CAST(YEAR([Date])-1 AS Varchar(4))+'/'+CAST(YEAR([Date]) AS Varchar(4)) 
                        ELSE CAST(YEAR([Date]) AS Varchar(4))+'/'+CAST(YEAR([Date])+1 AS Varchar(4)) END,
    FiscalQuarter = CASE WHEN MONTH([Date]) < @StartingMonthOfFiscalYear 
                        THEN ((MONTH([Date]) + 12 - @StartingMonthOfFiscalYear) / 3) + 1 
                        ELSE ((MONTH([Date]) - @StartingMonthOfFiscalYear) / 3) + 1 END
```

This updates over 47,000 rows in less than 1 second, saving us from having to recalculate every time we need it.

Answer (score 0):

I went looking for an answer today and decided that I should post my solution as it avoids a CASE statement:

```
select DATEPART(Quarter,dateadd(m,6,YourDate))/* add six months to move to FY */ qq
```

This is written for the Australian Financial year which is six months adjusted, you can see what I'm doing from this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question but the accepted answer does not seem correct. Financial quarter depends on which month the financial year starts, so it will always (?) be a calculation with 2 dates.

Here's what worked for me, no case statement:

```
CEILING((DATEDIFF(MONTH, FinYearStartDate, MonthStartDate)) / 3) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
MyDate,
CASE
    WHEN MONTH(MyDate) IN (1,2,3)  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(MyDate) - 1) + 'Q3'
    WHEN MONTH(MyDate) IN (4,5,6)  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(MyDate) - 1) + 'Q4'
    WHEN MONTH(MyDate) IN (7,8,9)  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(MyDate) - 0) + 'Q1'
    WHEN MONTH(MyDate) IN (10,11,12) THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(MyDate) - 0) + 'Q2'
END AS Quarter  FROM MyTable
```

The above answers do not consider the final month of the quarter

eg. between 1 and 3 will only return months 1 and 2...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Opendate,Month(Opendate),
       (CASE WHEN (Month(Opendate)/6.0)<=1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) HALF_YEAR 
FROM TableName where Opendate <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative to the accepted answer:

```
declare @tbl table (MyDate datetime)
insert into @tbl values ('2011-01-01')
insert into @tbl values ('2011-04-01')
insert into @tbl values ('2011-07-01')
insert into @tbl values ('2011-10-01')

SELECT CAST(MyDate AS DATE) as MyDate, CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -6, MyDate)) AS VARCHAR(4)) + 'Q'
    + CAST(DATEPART(q,DATEADD(MONTH, -6, MyDate)) AS VARCHAR(1)) AS Quarter
FROM @tbl
```

Output:

```
MyDate     Quarter
---------- -------
2011-01-01 2010Q3
2011-04-01 2010Q4
2011-07-01 2011Q1
2011-10-01 2011Q2
```

This works even if MyDate is something like August 31 - if you subtract 6 months from 8/31 in SQL, you get 2/28 (although 2/31 doesn't exist, MSSQL still knows you probably want the last day of the month). Since the quarter is based on the month of the year, this approach works.

Answer (score 0):

This code converts date to year and month, which is beginning of a quarter.

```
DATEADD(quarter, DATEDIFF(quarter, 0, @date), 0) year_and_first_month_of_quarter
```

So the months will be always: 
YYYY-**01**-01
YYYY-**04**-01
YYYY-**07**-01
YYYY-**10**-01
Good thing about it - result is in datetime format.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @sdate date='2017-12-01'
declare @edate date='2018-07-01'



;with rs as
(
   select   1 [QNum],@sdate StDT
   union all 
   select [QNum]+1, DATEADD(qq,1,stdt)   from rs where [QNum]<=datediff(qq,@sdate,@edate)
)
select QNum, convert(varchar(10),StDT,105) StDT,convert(varchar(10),dateAdd(m,3,DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(qq,DATEDIFF(qq, 0, stdt) + 1, 0))),105)EndDT from rs

--select left(datename(mm,s),3) + ' ' +cast(year(s) as varchar) from rs
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over this post by accident but didn't find a simple answer.  All I do is add the correct number of months using the applicable function and then take the strings needed for the proper quarter.  Keeping it simple is always the best.

Year end begins in Aug so push the date by 5 months.  An example in MSACCESS:

Quarter: DatePart('yyyy',DateAdd('m',+5,[YOURDATEFIELD])) & "/Q" & DatePart('q',DateAdd('m',+5,[YOURDATEFIELD]))

Answer (score 0):

I find this works really well to assign the quarters to the month range you want.

```
select

(CASE WHEN DatePart(m,mydate.mytable) > 4 THEN DatePart(yyyy,mydate.mytable)+1 ELSE DatePart(yyyy,mydate.mytable) END) AS FiscalYear,
    CASE
        WHEN MONTH(mydate.mytable) BETWEEN 1  AND 3  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(mydate.mytable) - 1) + 'Q3'
        WHEN MONTH(mydate.mytable) BETWEEN 4  AND 6  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(mydate.mytable) - 1) + 'Q4'
        WHEN MONTH(mydate.mytable) BETWEEN 7  AND 9  THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(mydate.mytable) - 0) + 'Q1'
        WHEN MONTH(mydate.mytable) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN convert(char(4), YEAR(mydate.mytable) - 0) + 'Q2'
    END AS Quarter

from

mytable
```

Answer (score -2):

it may helps someone

```
declare @dt uddt
select @dt=getdate()


select  case when month(@dt) between 1 and 3 then 'Q4' 
when month(@dt) between 4 and 6 then 'Q1'
when month(@dt) between 6 and 9 then 'Q2'
when month(@dt) between 9 and 12 then'Q3'
end as [Quarter] ,DATEADD(quarter, DATEDIFF(quarter, 0, @dt), 0) 
year_and_first_date_of_quarter,
DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(q,DATEDIFF(q, 0, @dt) + 1, 0)) 
year_and_last_date_of_quarter
```